# "I want to forget the little nuts"

Tags: japanese-language, music, humanity-has-declined

In the Ending animation sequence of Jintai, the song *Yume no Naka no Watashi no Yume
(My Dream Within a Dream)* plays with the following lyrics in romaji:

> Wasuretai tte kimochi
>   Sore mo uso ja nai kokoro

On [Anime Lyrics](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/jintai/yumenakawatashiyume.htm) it is translated so:

> The feeling of wanting to forget
>   It, too, is an emotion that is not a lie

But in the subs I have, it is translated like this:

> What is it?
>   There you sit on my lap, little squirrel
>   The chestnut is like your flag, you child of the forest, seeking courage
>
> When the sounds of March are all around, even the humans will know
>
> Day in, day out, I sow the seeds for the future
>   Eventually they bloom to flowers, and all feast on what it brought to fruit
>   My dream fulfills that of the others at the same time
>   Isn't it nice to make your wishes then?
>
> **I want to forget the little nuts
>
>   That's what I really feel like**
>
> What's wrong today?
>   You wave your chestnut like a flag, little squirrel
>   Soon you will run to the forest again, your refuge
>   What's wrong today?
>   Here you sit on my lap
>   Why don't you rest?

The animation sequence itself contains many objects that come directly from the story. Most of them I recognized, but where do these *little nuts* come from in the subtitle translation? Was it a mistranslation or some subtle reference to the events of the story? I wonder if the differences are because of some double-meaning words or some hidden context that one of the translators (or both) didn't get.

Comment: While I obviously can't be sure, it seems likely that the translator for the subtitles  misheard 気持ち _kimochi_ "feelings" as 木の実 _kinomi_ "nuts". I don't see any double meanings or hidden context here.

Comment: Okay, maybe not. Prior to releasing the BD version, Commie re-edited their Jintai subs, including parts of the ED. But by the time the BDs were out, the ED single had been released (with printed lyrics in the booklet), meaning there shouldn't have been any issues with mishearing lyrics. Yet, the "little nuts" line is present in both the TV and BD releases. This suggests that my previous comment is probably incorrect. Perhaps the translator _did_ know something that I don't.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the translation has been fixed in [your link](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/jintai/yumenakawatashiyume.htm), it no longer says nuts.

Also the original translation you quoted had many mistakes in it, for example this:

> You wave your chestnut like a flag, little squirrel

The lyrics at that point is `旗振る子リス` which means `Little squirrel waving a flag` transliterated, and nothing suggesting about waving chestnuts. In the corrected version on the site by Ohseki, it is now translated as `Little squirrel, waving your flag`.

I'm pretty sure that it was just a bad translation overall.

Comment: AFAIK, the Anime Lyrics has the correct translation since then. The quoted lyric is about the English sub (probably a fansub) translating it as "little nuts" instead of "feeling".